# Pandas: Convert a column into a unique list

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
df = pandas.read_excel("some_file.xlsx")

identifiers = df["some_data"] #it's a column with names


list = []

for i in identifiers:
        if i not in list:
                list.append(i)
```

Comment: You don't need a loop or list comprehension. You can just do df['some_data'].tolist()

Comment: @acrobat that would make a great answer if you included a way to handle the removal of duplicates implied by `if i not in list:`

Comment: @G. Anderson fair point. df['some_data'].unique().tolist() will do it

Comment: @acrobat better to answer as an answer, not as a comment, so that I can upvote and OP can accept it

Comment: @G.Anderson Done! Thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for any loops or list comprehension.

```
identifiers = df['some_data'].unique().tolist()
```

Comment: Nice answer.  +1 for providing the proper way, rather than the requested way.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
list = [i for i in pandas.read_excel("some_file.xlsx")["some data"] if i not in list]
```

Note: A name error may arise if you use the name list

Comment: But questions asks to do append operation instead of simple assignment

Comment: This will throw a `NameError` regardless, because your list is being built by the list comprehension, so it doesn't exist to be checked by the `if i not in` condition

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine:

```
f = [list.append(i) for i in identifiers if i not in list]
print(list)
```

You should not use `list` as a variable name, use name like `arr` for example

```
arr = []
f = [arr.append(i) for i in identifiers if i not in arr]
print(arr)
```

Comment: Have you tested this? `.append()` returns `none`, so f will equal `[None, None, None, None, None...`

Comment: f is of no use it is just to perform the operation, yes I have tested and it works. The value of f doesn't matter

Comment: Using a list comp in this way is technically working to produce the desired output, but the point of a list comprehension in the first place is to avoid using `.append()` at all

Comment: list comprehension is used to assign values and not to append in first place, hence my answer is a turn-around to append anyways

Comment: My answer satisfies the desired output, which was asked in first place, can you give me a reason for the downvote? Do you think this is misleading?